# Multiple CSS radio show hide on the same page

Tags: html, css

I have a working show/hide in CSS, using the radio type. All is good but when I try to add more then one show/hide they all open at the same time.
That makes sense to me, since they have the same ids and names. So I edited those, all is different, but when they go on the same page they lose the formatting and a mess comes out of it.

Any advice is appreciated (unless your advice is using js or jquery: I know it's easy with js but I really want to use css/html only)

Thanks!

```css
  /* showhide css */
  
input#show, input#hide {
    display:none;
}

div#paragraph {
    display:none;
}
input#show:checked ~ div#paragraph {
  display:block;
  float: left;
  padding-top:20px;
}

input#hide:checked ~ div#paragraph {
    display:none;
}

.showthis {
 float: left;
 background-color:#9b2f00;
 border-style: solid black 1px;
 color: #f2e07b; 
 padding: 5px;
 box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px black;
 text-align: center;
 width: 200px;
 font-size: 15px
}
.hidethis {
 float: right;
 background-color:#9b2f00;
 border-style: solid black 1px;
 color: #f2e07b; 
 padding: 5px;
 box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px black;
 font-size:13px;
  
  
 /* showhide css 01 */

input#show01, input#hide01 {
    display:none;
}

div#paragraph01 {
    display:none;
}
input#show01:checked ~ div#paragraph01 {
  display:block;
  float: left;
  padding-top:20px;
}

input#hide01:checked ~ div#paragraph01 {
    display:none;
}

.showthis01 {
 float: left;
 background-color:#9b2f00;
 border-style: solid black 1px;
 color: #f2e07b; 
 padding: 5px;
 box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px black;
 text-align: center;
 width: 200px;
 font-size: 15px
}
.hidethis01 {
 float: right;
 background-color:#9b2f00;
 border-style: solid black 1px;
 color: #f2e07b; 
 padding: 5px;
 box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px black;
 font-size:13px;
}
```

```html
 <label for="show">
 <span class="showthis">[Show]</span></label><input type=radio id="show" name="group"/><label for="hide"><span class="hidethis">[Hide]</span></label>    
<input type=radio id="hide" name="group"/>
<div id="paragraph">
This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
   it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
   the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
   (at your option) any later version.
   
  </div>
  
<br /><br /><br /> <br />
  
<label for="show01">
 <span class="showthis01">[Show01]</span></label><input type=radio id="show01" name="group01"/><label for="hide01"><span class="hidethis01">[Hide01]</span></label>    
<input type=radio id="hide01" name="group01"/>
<div id="paragraph01">
This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
   it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
   the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
   (at your option) any later version.
   
  </div>
```

Comment: Don’t use ids, use classes instead …?

Comment: You mean changing all the ids to classes? I gave it a try right now but is interesting, even a single show/hide is not working that way

Comment: is it ok use use checkbox so show/hide on one?

Comment: You mean using radio button on one and checkbox for the other? 
I thought about that but in some pages I may have 4, 5 paragraph that I would like to separate like this, so 2 options are not enough. I tried checkbox in the past and they gave me similar problem.

Comment: I mean use checkbox for all, I'll put it together in a jsfiddle shortly.

Comment: Yeah well, we can give it a try! I'll wait for a little code of your, eventually I'll pass to checkbox =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to use next selector `+` for show/hide a single item and use sibling `~` for all.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/qjsmm6eq/3/

HTML

```
<label for="all">show all</label>
<input type="radio" name="radio" class="showall"/>

<label for="all">hide all</label>
<input type="radio" name="radio" class="hideall" />

<br/><br/><br/><br/>

<label for="a">show/hide</label>
<input type="radio" name="radio" class="single" />
<div class="content">a</div>

<br/><br/>

<label for="b">show/hide</label>
<input type="radio" name="radio" class="single" />
<div class="content">b</div>
```

CSS

```
.content {
    visibility: hidden;
    color: red;
}

.single:checked + .content {
    visibility: visible;
}

.showall:checked ~ .content {
    visibility: visible;
}

.hideall:checked ~ .content {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

**EDIT:** The checkbox solution is available here http://jsfiddle.net/qjsmm6eq/

**EDIT 2:** Changed back to `radio`, show/hide all on two buttons, and one for single item, the best I can do for now.

Comment: You both give a proper, working answer and a useful idea with the checkbox thing (I added that in my reply). I thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the idea of sdcr (thank you very much!) and used checkboxes: they worked great, so even though is not a proper answer since my original question was different I paste the code anyway:

```css
/* Showhide CSS only */ 
 
/* function */

label {
  cursor: pointer;
}
#showhide {
  display: none; /* hide the checkbox */
}
#paragraph {
  display: none;
}
#showhide:checked + #paragraph {
  display: block;
}

/* Showhide CSS only 02*/ 
label {
  cursor: pointer;
}
#showhide01 {
  display: none; /* hide the checkbox */
}
#paragraph01 {
  display: none;
}
#showhide01:checked + #paragraph01 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
 <label for="showhide"><span class="title">I am the first</span></label>
<input type="checkbox" id="showhide"/>
<div id="paragraph">
  original text
</div> 
<br /> <br />

 <label for="showhide01"><span class="title">I am the second</span></label>
<input type="checkbox" id="showhide01"/>
<div id="paragraph01">
  secondary text
</div>
```